# Difficulty in running Tomcat v7.0 with Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, windows-xp

I get the following error when I run my JSP file in Eclipse-Juno with Tomcat v7:

> 'starting Tomcat v7.0 server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>   Port 8080 required by Tomcat v7.0 server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I have Oracle 10g installed in my System. When I type "http://localhost:8080" it opens the 
Oracle 10g license agreement so I think Oracle 10g is already running in that port.

To change the port of Tomcat I tried Google, which said to change the port in the "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\conf\httpd.conf" file

But at "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\conf" there was no httpd.conf file.
I only have "catalina.policy,catalina.properties,context,logging.properties,server,tomcat-users,web" files in that conf folder.
I use windows XP.

Comment: FWIW - I think you misread the page you were looking at.  "...\conf\httpd.conf" is the pathname for the main config file for Apache Httpd, not Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "server.xml":

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

  EXAMPLE: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\conf\server.xml

`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Answer (score 0):

there is a software in your system use port 8080
double click on your server configuration on server view and under the port section,
change it to something else Ex:9090

[image]

if you trying to run tomcat outside of eclipse 
locate apache-tomcat-install-dir\conf\server.xml
and change the port there.